# What is the meaning of mounting /dev/sda1 to /etc/hosts in Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, mount, hosts

I run a simple docker container with `sudo docker run -it ubuntu:latest /bin/bash`

When I examine mounted file system, with: `df -h`, one

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          63G  4.3G   56G   8% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs          1000M     0 1000M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1        63G  4.3G   56G   8% /etc/hosts
....
```

I fail to understand the last line, i.e. `/dev/sda1 -> /etc/hosts`, when I run `df -h` on the host machine, I get the mount `/dev/sda1 -> /`.

So `/dev/sda1` is actually my hard drive, why is it mounted to `/etc/hosts` on the container, and how come `/etc/hosts` on the container is a file with correct content.

Any explanation of what is going on here? how does this work?

Comment: The output is a bit misleading. Only the hosts file is mounted into the container because docker needs to control its content.

Comment: @Henry The `/etc/hosts` file in the container is not mounted from the host, it is a different file

Comment: Exactly, it is a file controlled by docker (most likely somewhere below /var/lib/docker). It is not the /etc/hosts of the docker host.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have two questions in your post, let me cover them sequentially.

**1) Why `/etc/{hosts,hostname,resolv.conf}` files are mounted from outside?**

I see at least one reason for this.

Imagine what would happen if the container engine would simply write these files to the container's filesystem **and** the user would decide to mount `/etc` as a volume (which is perfectly legal and pretty useful - mounting `/etc` would allow the user to provide the container with multiple config files in one `-v` argument for `docker run`):

- first, the volume is mounted to container's `/etc` directory;
- then its content is changed by the container engine (a write to specific files in `/etc`).

After launching this container, the user tries to launch one more with the same `/etc` volume (again, this is perfectly legal and useful - e.g. the user scales up some service and shares config files in `/etc` among instances), and... The second container overwrites `hostname`, `hosts` and `resolv.conf` files on the volume, affecting the first container.

Now consider what happens when bind-mounting is used instead of direct writes:

- the volume is mounted to container's `/etc` directory;
- the container engine bind-mounts `/etc/{hosts,hostname,resolv.conf}` from somewhere on the host to the container's filesystem;
- bind-mounts *hide* the original versions (if any) of these files on the volume, hence the guarantee that the files on the volume will not be modified during the container setup and will not be propagated to other containers.

**2) Why I see `/dev/sda1` as the source of these mounts?**

Check `findmnt(8)` instead of `df(1)`:

```
$ docker run -it ubuntu
root@5a8ab4d6e716:/# findmnt
TARGET                           SOURCE
...
|-/etc/resolv.conf               /dev/sda1[/var/lib/docker/containers/5a8ab4d6e71691f279cbbcf5a295b5fa90fd138f10418c996ad7ea4440452816/resolv.conf]
|-/etc/hostname                  /dev/sda1[/var/lib/docker/containers/5a8ab4d6e71691f279cbbcf5a295b5fa90fd138f10418c996ad7ea4440452816/hostname]
`-/etc/hosts                     /dev/sda1[/var/lib/docker/containers/5a8ab4d6e71691f279cbbcf5a295b5fa90fd138f10418c996ad7ea4440452816/hosts]
```

Actually, each line of output here shows *three* fields (mount target `/etc/hosts`, mount source `/dev/sda1` and FS root `/var/lib/<...>/hosts`), and the third one is not shown by `df(1)`.

According to `man procfs` paragraph about `/proc/PID/mountinfo` file (which is the source of information about mounts for utilities):

```
(4)  root: the pathname of the directory in the filesystem which forms the root of this mount.
(5)  mount point: the pathname of the mount point relative to the process's root directory.
...
(10) mount source: filesystem-specific information or "none".
```

For most mounts, FS root is `/` (because you mount whole filesystem), so you don't loose too much information when you look at the `df(1)` output. However, this is not the case for bind-mounts of specific files.